# Kendo-Angular: Disable select file button in kendo-upload

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-upload

I have implemented kendo upload in my angular project

component.html

```
    <kendo-upload
    #upload
    [autoUpload]="false"
    (select)="onSelectEvent($event)"
  (remove)="onRemoveEvent($event, upload)"
  (upload)="onUploadEvent($event)"
  [multiple]="false"
  [restrictions]="myRestrictions">
  </kendo-upload>
```

[image]

I want to disable the 'Select file' button once the file is selected as in picture and enable once  user clicks on clear button or 'X'.

Please help me with your suggestions as I'm new to Kendo and couldn't find documentation.

Comment: Hello Kiran, Can You say are you on what version of angular and kendo ui ?

Comment: @GRD angular version is 12+ and Kendo version is 5, which I can see in my package.json file

Comment: Did you find out solution for this yet ? Or are you still looking for the solutions ?

Comment: @GRD I have used the kendo upload [disabled] property as suggested by misha130

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file upload offers a disable attribute. Here is a demo:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/uploads/upload/disabled-state/

So for example:

```
<kendo-upload [disabled]="hasFile$ | async"> </kendo-upload>
```

Where hasFile$ is:

```
public hasFile$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

If you only use a boolean instead of an observable the change detection won't pick it up

To only disable the button and not the rest of the upload:

```
(this.upload.fileSelectButton.nativeElement as HTMLElement).classList.add('k-state-disabled');
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but this disables entire upload section along with 'X' mark, so user cannot remove the attached file and upload again.

Comment: You have (this.upload as UploadComponent).fileSelectButton or (this.upload as UploadComponent).fileSelect which both have disabled properties. I don't have an environment right now to test this but thats probably the way to go. Access the file-select and disable it in the ts

Comment: Added to the answer a way to disable only the button